# atapi.sys causes BSOD since Windows 10

Tags: drivers, bsod, atapi

Ever since I upgraded my aging notebook (Fujitsu E8310, love the 4:3 screen!), I am experiencing a BSOD DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE after waking up from sleep/suspend. So I decided to get it fixed once and for all, but I am stuck.

I looked at the minidump, and to me it seems to be the atapi.sys. Now I remember I have had problems before with Windows 7 x64 that after resuming from sleep, the DVD-drive wasn't working anymore, that includes not even opening the drive bay, and disappearing from "My Computer". After reboot, everything was back to normal. I don't recall if this has been like that from the beginning when I installed Windows 7. This seems to be connected to the drive waiting too long on IRP. From my findings, this error wasn't throwing a BSOD in Windows 7, but from Windows 8 and on this condition WILL throw a BSOD. So while it just left me with a non-working DVD-drive on Win7, it crashes the computer on Win10.

I have updated all drivers to the latest versions I could find (even modded Intel RST drivers), but they never include the atapi.sys. Since this drive is still using the IDE bus, updating the RST driver obviously does nothing. Also the drive and BIOS are updated to the latest firmware version.

At the moment I have 2 workarounds:
1) Never sleep
2) Disable IDE in BIOS and activate when I need the drive (requiring reboot).

Is there maybe a way to deactivate the BSOD condition on DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE? Or is there an updated atapi.sys somewhere? The one in Win10 is from 2006. Or is maybe related to the drive and changing to another one could help (if I can still find an IDE drive somewhere!)?

Thank you everyone for your input!

EDIT: The notebook is using ICH8M chipset. HDD is in native AHCI mode (no legacy).

EDIT2: It is also on a fresh install, fully updated. Here's the crashdump btw.: https://www.sendspace.com/file/lsl3b6

Comment: share the dmp, maybe I can see more details.

Comment: There you go: https://www.sendspace.com/file/lsl3b6

Answer (score 0):

ok, I checked the dmp and see that the CD/DVD drive (`"IDE\CdRomMATSHITA_DVD-RAM_UJ-850S________________1.40____\5&243ced04&0&0.0.0"`) causes the issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe001d54a81f0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff801ec447ad0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe001d76aac10, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.103.amd64fre.th2_release.160126-1819

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  FUJITSU SIEMENS

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  LIFEBOOK E8310

BIOS_VENDOR:  FUJITSU // Phoenix Technologies Ltd.

BIOS_VERSION:  Version 1.16 

BIOS_DATE:  05/31/2010

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  FUJITSU

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  FJNB1CE

IMAGE_NAME:  atapi.sys

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
02 nt!PopIrpWatchdog
03 nt!KiRetireDpcList
04 nt!KiIdleLoop


BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.103.amd64fre.th2_release.160126-1819

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_image_atapi.sys


0: kd> !irp ffffe001d76aac10
Irp is active with 6 stacks 4 is current (= 0xffffe001d76aadb8)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe001d54a81f0 00000000 00000000-00000000    pending
           \Driver\atapi
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe001d55cfba0 00000000 fffff801ea590dc8-ffffe001d53e7400 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\cdrom    nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000

0: kd> !podev ffffe001d54a81f0
Device object is for:
  DriverObject d5c3cc30
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000002 AttachedDev ffffe001d5479830 DevFlags 00005050 DO_POWER_INRUSH
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe001d54a8b80:
PowerFlags: 00000041 =>SystemState=1 DeviceState=4
Dope: d5f03780:
0: kd> !devstack ffffe001d5479830
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe001d55cfba0  \Driver\cdrom      ffffe001d55d4b60  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe001d55cfb70

!DevNode ffffe001d5c59d30 :
  DeviceInst is "IDE\CdRomMATSHITA_DVD-RAM_UJ-850S________________1.40____\5&243ced04&0&0.0.0"
  ServiceName is "cdrom"
```

So look if the DVD Drive is running in IDE mode (if the drive is SATA) and configure it to be SATA Mode (in BIOS).

Comment: Thank you. I also figured that out. I thought it was clear from my writing. The drive is an IDE drive. This is why I cannot use it if I disable IDE mode for this drive.

Comment: try to use the drive in an external USB dvd enclosure and only connect it if you need the DVD drive

Comment: This is not really an option, because then I tend to not have it with me when I need it. This is why I am trying to figure out how to fix this. I'd rather buy a different internal drive.

Comment: look if you can disable power saving settings in device manager

Comment: Hm, no, as soon as it enters suspend it will override those settings.

Comment: I have no other idea how to fix this.